# LoadOptions is not been called second time if the input is same in react select async paginate

Tags: reactjs

I have been using react-select-async-paginate and i want that every time load option showuld call itself even if the input is same.
Below is my code :

```
<AsyncPaginate
 debounceTimeout={300}
 value={value}
 onChange={manageDropDownClick}
 loadOptions={(Search, prevOptions, { page }) =>
    loadOptions(Search, prevOptions, { page }, checked)
 }
 placeholder="Search Customers.."
 additional={{
 page: 1,
 }}
 onInputChange={onInputChange}
 inputValue={inputValue}
 noOptionsMessage={(e) => noOptionsMessage(e)}
 loadingMessage={() => "Searching..."}
 onMenuClose={() => setValue([])}
 />
```

Can any one help me with this please...